# awk assign $1 column to a shell variable and replace $1 with command output

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Some command output is:

```
192.168.0.1 value1
192.168.0.2 value2
192.168.0.3 value3
192.168.0.4 value4
```

I need to pass it to awk and replace IPs with hostnames, which I'm gettin' with next command:

```
$ knife search node -i public_ipv4:192.168.0.1

server1
```

So I need to assign $1 column value of cmd output to $ip variable and pass it back to knife cmd, as **ip=$1**:

```
$ cmd |awk -v ip=$1 -v name="$(knife search node -i public_ipv4:$ip)" '{$1=name}1'
```

expecting output:

```
server1 value1
server2 value2
server3 value3
server4 value4
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk`'s `getline` function:

```
command | awk '{"knife search node -i public_ipv4:"$1 | getline h; print h, $2}'
```

The above command executes the `knife` command and reads it's outputs into a variable `h`.

Comment: Thank you, it's working too, but one thing: chefs' knife search full output contains `1 items found \n server1`, so `getline h` working not every time. How can I pass through that?

Comment: added `" |grep pattern"` after $1 and everything seems to work as expected

Comment: Ah ok. I have unfortunately no `knife search`  command by the hand for testing.

Answer (score 4):

It will be easier to handle it in shell itself using `read` and [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst):

```
while read -r ip val; do
   echo "$(knife search node -i public_ipv4:$ip) $val"
done < <(cmd)
```

In your `awk` command `-v ip=$1` isn't going to work because `$1` is dynamic awk value which will change for each line and cannot be used using `-v name=value` argument.

Comment: But why do you set IFS to an empty string?

Comment: I've just tried it and I see that the whole line is assigned to the `ip` variable while `val` remains empty.

Comment: You're right, `IFS=` shouldn't be there to split the fields on space.